# Format 10-digit string into hyphenated phone number

Tags: php, string, formatting, phone-number, text-parsing

I have a string containing a ten-digit phone number and I want to format it with hyphens.

I am seeking a way to convert `123456790` to `123-456-7890` as phone numbers are typically formatted in the USA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$areacode = substr($phone, 0, 3);
$prefix   = substr($phone, 3, 3);
$number   = substr($phone, 6, 4);

echo "$areacode-$prefix-$number";
```

You could also do it with regular expressions:

```
preg_match("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/",$phone,$matches);
echo "$matches[1]-$matches[2]-$matches[3]";
```

There are more ways, but either will work.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will also validate your input.

```
preg_match('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $phone, $matches);

if ($matches) {
    echo(implode('-', array_slice($matches, 1)));
}
else {
    echo($phone); // you might want to handle wrong format another way
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$p = $phone; 
echo "$p[0]$p[1]$p[2]-$p[3]$p[4]-$p[5]$p[6]$p[7]$p[8]";
```

Fewest function calls. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo substr($phone, 0, 3) . '-' . substr($phone, 3, 3) . '-' . substr($phone, 6);
```

[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

More regexp :)

```
$phone = "1234567890";
echo preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', '\1-\2-\3', $phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a regular expression, I would not bother creating a temporary array to conver back into a string.  Instead just tell `preg_replace()` to make a maximum of two replacements after each sequence of three digits.

As a non-regex alternative, you could parse the string and reformat it using placeholders with `sscanf()` and `vprintf()`.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gSJje))

```
$string = '1234567890';

echo preg_replace('/\d{3}\K/', '-', $string, 2);
// 123-456-7890
```

Or

```
vprintf('%s-%s-%s', sscanf($string, '%3s%3s%4s'));
// 123-456-7890
```

Or

```
echo implode('-', sscanf($string, '%3s%3s%4s'));
// 123-456-7890
```

---

For such a simple task, involving a library is super-overkill, but for more complicated tasks there are libraries available:

- https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php/blob/master/docs/PhoneNumberUtil.md
- https://github.com/brick/phonenumber