# Change format of phone number

Tags: php, regex, string, formatting, phone-number

I have string with phone number that I need to transform from one format to another.

Example:

```
"02030266079" => "0203 026 6079"
```

I tried:

```
$num = "02030266079";
$transformed= preg_replace("/^(/d{4})(/d{3})(/d{4})$/", "$1 $2 $3", $num);
```

But nothing happens!

Comment: Also, as a starting point you have to define clear rules _how_ the transformation should be done. An example is not enough here. Especially since most likely one requires knowledge about where to place those spaces. Knowledge about what part of the sequence is an area code and the like. This is not trivial.

Comment: Read this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php

Comment: Start by explaining the pattern that defines the format - eg. InternationalDialingCode+LocalDiallingCode+Number

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this site and I promise to ask better questions next time.

Comment: @user2546940 no prob, next time you should come with attempts. Here `preg_replace('~(?<=^\d{4})|(?=\d{4}$)~', ' ', $str);` is the answer for this question.

Comment: @user2546940 You don't have to wait until next time. You can [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30478285/edit) your question right now

Comment: You can use this awesome library to change the format of your number to different international of local formats https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php http://giggsey.com/libphonenumber/

Comment: Digit is `\d` not `/d`

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = "12345678901";
$formatted_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1 $2 $3", $number);
```

It is php code and well tested, It works perfectly