# Format phone number to be valid E164 format using libphonenumber-for-php library

Tags: php, validation, formatting, phone-number, sanitization

I want to check that an entered phone number is a valid E164-formatted phone number; if not, then convert it to proper E164 format.

Comment: We have try following link code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php

Comment: I expect that you should be able to customize this comprehensive script to suit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551677/2943403

Comment: Or maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725560/2943403) on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Use Regular Expressions in PHP.

The regex I had to come up with that works along with '+' sign along with the digits which much reside between 10~15 is as follows:

> ^+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$

And this works well. You can check it out on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Why is the `+` allowed to occur unlimited times? Why are you engaging a lazy quantifier when the regex engine will be matching plus symbols until it encounters a digit. Why use the verbose `[0-9]` then immediately use the shorter +\d`?  Why not just adjust the quantifier range and write a DRYer pattern? I don't find this pattern to be very thoughtful/refined.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, I believe you are right. This was from four years ago when I solved a similar situation. Maybe the situation here for this question was quite different. Now I understand things a bit differently. Based upon that I have updated the regular expression. Could you check now if it's better?