# I want to Display Phone number in this format XXX-XXX-XXXX. I tried many way but cant get the correct answer

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to display phone number in this format `XXX-XXX-XXXX`. But now it's displaying like this `XXX-XXX-XXX-X`

```
<div class="row mb15">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
        <p>Home Phone</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 phone-number">
        <h4><?php echo join('-', str_split($candidateDet['homephone'], 3)); ?></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternative ideas are welcome

Comment: The result is absolutely coherent with your code. Since your formatting is irregular, you may make an iterative function that explicitly take the first 3 char, insert '-', 3 next, insert '-' and append the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Phone Numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php)

Comment: Remember the conventional way of displaying phone numbers varies by country.  So, f you are targeting an international audience you might want to localise this appropriately.

Comment: thank you all. For your valuable reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace()` to find and group the numbers.

Something like:

```
echo preg_replace('#(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})#', '$1-$2-$3', $phoneNumber);
```

[An example](https://3v4l.org/ZfPKN).