# Function to add dashes to US phone number in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best way to add dashes to a phone number in PHP? I have a number in the format `xxxxxxxxxx` and I want it to be in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx. This only applies to 10 digit US phone numbers.

Comment: I think `add_dashes_to_number()` might work ;)

Comment: This is supposed to be a serious question. I wasn't sure whether substr, str_split, chunk_split or something else would be the best thing to use.

Comment: why wouldnt you use jquery validation or something and handle this on client side?

Comment: Because it might screw up the serverside. I'm not sure how, but it might.

Comment: Because I want a server side solution so that the format is always the same regardless of js.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$number = "1234567890";
$formatted_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $number);
```

**EDIT**: To be a bit more generic and normalize a US phone number given in any of a variety of formats (which should be common practice - there's no reason to force people to type in a phone number in a specific format, since all you're interested in are the digits and you can simply discard the rest):

```
function localize_us_number($phone) {
  $numbers_only = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $phone);
  return preg_replace("/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $numbers_only);
}

echo localize_us_number("5551234567"), "\n";
echo localize_us_number("15551234567"), "\n";
echo localize_us_number("+15551234567"), "\n";
echo localize_us_number("(555) 123-4567"), "\n";
echo localize_us_number("+1 (555) 123-4567"), "\n";
echo localize_us_number("Phone: 555 1234567 or something"), "\n";
```

Comment: I did some tests and this is the fastest method

Comment: @Galen: be wary of absolutes like "Fastest". A faster solution then this is `$formatted = "$number[0]$number[1]$number[2]-$number[3] ...` til the string is done.

Comment: By fastest i meant fastest of the methods that were provided at that time

Comment: Fast shouldn't really matter here unless you plan on applying this to aproximately 4,567,138,234,234 phone numbers at a time.

Comment: To take this a step further, prepare the pattern for an extension of an indefinite number of digits.                                               $formatted_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{1,})$/", "$1-$2-$3-$4", $number);

Comment: In my case, this worked out:
**$formatted_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{7})$/", "$1-$2", $number);**

Comment: Saved me tons of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
$number = '1234567890';
if(ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) == 10) {
  $number = substr($number, 0, 3) .'-'.
            substr($number, 3, 3) .'-'.
            substr($number, 6);
}
```

Or if you for some reason want to avoid substr:

```
$number = '1234567890';
if(ctype_digit($number) && strlen($number) == 10) {
  $parts = str_split($number, 3);
  $number = $parts[0] .'-'. $parts[1] .'-'. $parts[3].$parts[4];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate through the string and make counter. When counter is 3 or 7 insert dash.

Answer (score 1):

I feel obliged to post. Cheesiest solution:

```
$number = "1234567890";
$formatted_number = "$number[0]$number[1]$number[2]-$number[3]$number[4]$number[5]-$number[6]$number[7]$number[8]$number[9]";
```

But it works and its fast. vs. the preg_replace solution:

250,000 iterations:

preg_replace: 1.23 seconds
ugly solution: 0.866 seconds

Pretty meaningless but fun :P

Comment: Now plug "foo" into your string. Poof. With preg_replace, all you get is the original string back if the regex doesn't match. I'd choose robustness vs speed here. :)

Comment: oh i wasn't suggesting you USE the above code. I posted it really because of galen's comment, and it amused me. Your original question gave the assumption of a string of 10 digits, for which this works. You didn't say anything about validating it as a proper phone number.

Comment: Wasn't my question, just my answer. I'm just advocating defensive coding practices.

Comment: to be honest, I didn't even know this solution was even possible.

Comment: @thilo in most cases I would have answered very similarly to you. Actually I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315355/how-can-i-split-this-string-with-a-hyphen/2315377#2315377  months ago, to a nearly identical question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used. It's not perfect, but it's an improvement over @Thilo's answer. It checks for a leading `1`. If it's there, it ignores it. The code also ignores separating dashes, commas, and spaces, so it will work with `1231231234`, `123 123 1234`, and `123.123.1234`. It doesn't handle numbers with parenthesis, but I'm sure there's another thread out there with that solution!

```
$formatted_number = preg_replace("/^1?(?:[- .])?(\d{3})(?:[- .])?(\d{3})(?:[- .])?(\d{4})$/", "($1) $2-$3", $not_formatted_phone_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

A modification of Thilo's answer providing complete conditional formatting control over the leading "1".

```
public function phoneFormat($number) {
        $numbersOnly = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $number);
        $nums = array_filter(explode("-", preg_replace("/^(1|)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/",
                                                            "$1-$2-$3-$4", $numbersOnly)));
        $output = $numbersOnly;
        if(count($nums) == 3){
            $output = "($nums[1])-$nums[2]-$nums[3]";
        }elseif(count($nums) == 4){
            $output = "$nums[0]-($nums[1])-$nums[2]-$nums[3]";
        }
        return $output;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function format_phone($var_num) {
    $var_num = trim($var_num);
    $var_num = str_replace("(","",$var_num);
    $var_num = str_replace(")","",$var_num);
    $var_num = str_replace("-","",$var_num);
    $var_num = str_replace(" ","",$var_num);
    $var_num = str_replace(".","",$var_num);
    $var_num = substr($var_num, -10);
    $var_area_code = substr($var_num, 0, -7);
    $var_exchange = substr($var_num, 3, -4);
    $var_extention = substr($var_num, -4);
    $var_return = "{$var_area_code}-{$var_exchange}-{$var_extention}";
    return $var_return;
}

// Examples:
$phone_number = "1 (757) 555-1212";
// $phone_number = "17575551212";
// $phone_number = "(757) 555-1212";
// $phone_number = "757.555.1212";
echo "{$phone_number} = " . format_phone($phone_number);
```

Comment: preg (regular expressions) work much better than using str_replace

Comment: String Replace uses Reg Ex. The idea is to valilidate the 10 digit phone number the user enters into a form in whatever format. The funtion then removes any formatting the user puts in, leaving only the ten digtits, then displays the phone number is a specified format.