# Convert bigInt(10) into formatted phone # in Codeigniter / MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am storing U.S. phone numbers in MySql table as a bigInt(10).

Example: 1234567890

I want to convert that into a formatted phone number in either mysql or php

Example: 1234567890 => (123) 456-7890

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: i think this is already answered here: using php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you format a 10 digit string into a phone number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089923/how-do-you-format-a-10-digit-string-into-a-phone-number)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872096/function-to-add-dashes-to-us-phone-number-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function format_phone_number($number)
  $number_string = '('.substr($number, 0, 3).') ';
  $number_string .= substr($number, 3, 3).'-';
  $number_string .= substr($number, 6);
  return $number_string;
}
?>
```

Here, we use the `substr` function three times to grab small text substrings of the whole number string. Remember that upon using this function, PHP will automatically turn the number into a string, so you don't have to worry about calling a string function on a variable that is the number type. It appends the extra characters `(`, `)`, and `-` by using PHP's concatenation operator, the period. I split it up into three statements just for manageability, though you could perform this whole function in one long line if you'd like, as follows:

```
<?php
function format_phone_number($number)
  return '('.substr($number, 0, 3).') '.substr($number, 3, 3).'-'.substr($number, 6);
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried to use your code and names the $number as my variable value (the #) but I got no result  <?php
   
     $number = $row->biz_phone;
   
   function format_phone_number($number){
     $number_string = '('.substr($number, 0, 3).') ';
     $number_string .= substr($number, 3, 3).'-';
     $number_string .= substr($number, 6);
     return $number_string;
   }
  ?>

Comment: here is the solution that worked: <?php
   $num = $row->biz_phone;  // given                                                  
   $formatted = "(".substr($num,0,3).") ".substr($num,3,3)."-".substr($num,6);
   echo $formatted;
  ?>

Comment: To use a function in PHP, you must declare it as you have done, and then you have to call it at some point. For example, you would use the code `<?php $num = $row->biz_phone; echo format_phone_number($num); function format_phone_number($number){ $number_string = '('.substr($number, 0, 3).') '; $number_string .= substr($number, 3, 3).'-'; $number_string .= substr($number, 6); return $number_string; } ?>` Sorry this wasn't clear. Glad to see you got it working without the use of a function.