# convert varchar[ ] column type to uuid[ ]

Tags: sql, postgresql

there is a column of type character varying[] , which contains data of type uuid like
`{0f071799-e37e-4e1c-9620-e580447416fe,913a7134-6092-45fa-ae18-163302db8112}`,

but there are also some old values of another type like `{5edfd4edfa1bb21a142442a0}`.

**How can the column type be converted?**
I used the script:

`alter table services alter column office_ids type uuid[] USING office_ids::uuid[];`

but gives an error - invalid syntax for type uuid: "5edfd4edfa1bb21a142442a0".

Comment: Those values have a different format, not type. You'll have to modify those strings so they have the same format as the others

Comment: I can't manually change them in the database, even if there aren't many of them. I need to write a script, but I don't know how to do it right yet.

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid UUID, it's just 25 digits instead of 32. To what valid content would you like to convert this example?

Comment: Kind of topically related: [Format 32-character string with hyphens to become UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33484743/2943403)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must first convert your 25 character values into valid `uuid` values.

One such conversion would be:

```
8f5f7cc46821423fa6057025a -> 00000008-f5f7-cc46-8214-23fa6057025a
```

The SQL for this is:

```
regexp_replace('8f5f7cc46821423fa6057025a', '^(.)(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})^', '0000000\1-\2-\3-\4-\5')
```

output:

```
00000008-f5f7-cc46-8214-23fa6057025a
```

Which leaves valid uuids unchanged. See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/87581).

You can use this to update the bad values like this:

```
update services set office_ids = array(
  select regexp_replace(t.val, '^(.)(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$', '0000000\1-\2-\3-\4-\5')
  from unnest(services.office_ids) as t(val)
)
```

Then your alter command will work.

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ce0c/1).